# Flex/Air replacement for desktop

Tags: java, ios, apache-flex, rest, air

I want to create a simple desktop admin application for an IOS app that will work with a REST api I've built.

Couple of years ago I would go with Flex/Air, just makes it very simple. But since I am butt-hurt with the way Adobe have handled Flash in general, I am looking to write it using some different tool.

So far, Java Swing looks rubbish (UI-wise I mean). Others aren't cross platform and often too complicated.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you heard of JavaFx

http://javafx.com/

Check it out, it is cross platform and a good UI framework for RIA